# applications of Tate-Poitou duality

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cohomology, big-list, motivation

What are nice applications of Tate-Poitou duality?

Answer (score 11):

One of the main themes of current number theory research, instigated by the work of Wiles and Taylor--Wiles on the Shimura--Taniyama modularity conjecture for elliptic curves, is the study of modularity (or more generally automorphy) of representations of Galois groups.   The basic tool for proving modularity is the so-called Taylor--Wiles method, which involves introducing certain well-chosen auxiliary primes to aid in analyzing a generalized Selmer group (a certain
Galois cohomology group) which controls the infinitesimal structure of the space of Galois
representations.

In applying this method, one relies on a certain formula (due to Greenberg and Wiles) which
expresses the ratio of the orders of a Selmer group and the corresponding dual Selmer group
in terms of a product of local terms, and the proof of this formula is an application of the
Poitou--Tate exact sequence.  See Washington's article in "Modular forms and Fermat's
Last Theorem" for an exposition of the Greenberg--Wiles formula.

There are lots of similar applications of Poitou--Tate in Iwasawa theory.  Whenever one studies Selmer groups, one confronts the problem of trying to analyze a global object
which is defined in terms of local conditions.  The Poitou--Tate exact sequence provides a relationship between local and global Galois cohomology groups, and so is fairly ubiquitous in the study of Selmer groups.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the recent paper of Mazur and Rubin, "Ranks of twists of elliptic curves and Hilbert's 10th problem"

Lemma 3.2, one of the indispensable lemmas of the paper, is a direct application of the Poitou-Tate exact sequence.

Comment: +1, that's actually an excellent example, both in terms of the importance of the result and the importance of the role Poitou-Tate plays there.

Answer (score 4):

There are loads of applications and what you consider "nice" hugely depends. One application
is e.g. Tate's proof that the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture is invariant under isogenies. That and more applications are contained in [Milne's book](http://jmilne.org/math/Books/index.html) on "Arithmetic Duality Theorems".

Answer (score 3):

Three examples of the use of the Poitou-Tate duality:

All parity results (Dokchitsers, Mazur-Rubin, Nekovar, ...) for elliptic curve use this duality somewhere.

The duality is also crucial for Euler systems. An Euler system produces a collection of "derived" global cohomology classes. Using the pairing induces by Poitou-Tate, one can show that these classes are not in the Selmer group but orthogonal to it. This then bounds the size of the Selmer group from above.

The Poitou-Tate duality is an analogue of the Poincaré duality. For instance, Tate reduced the conjecture of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer over a global field of characteristic $p$ to the finiteness of Sha. This argument uses Poincaré duality on the corresponding ellitic surface over the finite field. Analogous in Iwasawa theory, one uses the (Cassels-)Poitou-Tate duality in the computation of the leading term of the characteristic series of the Selmer group of the elliptic curve.

I would suspect there are more examples in "Cohomology of Number Fields".

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Galois cohomology of elliptic curves](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cohomology-Elliptic-Institute-Fundamental-Publication/dp/8173192936%20/%22cohomology%20of%20elliptic%20curves%22) by Coates and Sujatha is a good place to see some of the applications to Iwasawa theory as mentioned by prof Emerton.

Answer (score 1):

It has applications to the Brauer-Manin obstruction for torsors under connected linear algebraic groups, see Sansuc, J.-J., *Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres*, J. Reine Angew. Math. **327** (1981), 12–80 for number fields and Diego Izquierdo, *Dualité et principe local-global sur des corps locaux de dimension 2*, http://www.math.ens.fr/~izquierdo/Localdim204052016.pdf